# Implementing N-dim arrays in Erlang

Tags: arrays, erlang

I have an Erlang project requiring generating a nested list of array indices. Perhaps using `arrays:` would be a quick solution, but I would like to see how this is done without that module.

If one knows the number of dimensions of an array, creating a nested list of array indices can be done in one line eg.

```erlang
array2Dim(M,N) -> [[[X,Y] || X <- lists:seq(1,N)] || Y <- lists:seq(1,M)].
```

I've been struggling to implement a function, say `arrayNDim/1` that will take a list `[D1,D2,..., Dn]` of unknown length containing dimensions to generate the indices of the `D1 x D2 x...,Dn` array.

I have thought about spawning processes as a 'gear train' to produce the structure but I suspect the solution might be much simpler.

Comment: I think it is not exactly and array but more like coordinate mesh or like vector values mesh ? I think def you have to use recursion here but I am not sure that list generation is a way to go for ndim.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is using a Cartesian product of lists `[1,...,D1], [1..,D2],...,[1...Dn]`.
As in the question Cartesian products are easy with list comprehensions but only straightforward when the number of factors is known.
What I ended up doing was writing a generalised outer product function `outer/3` that takes two lists and a product function as arguments. By taking something like `fun(X,Y) -> [X,Y] end` as the product and with a judicious use of `lists:flatten/2` we *almost* have our Cartesian product. I say *almost* as the result is not a tree of coordinates but rather a flattened list `[[1,..,1],[1,..,2],...]` of coordinates. For my purposed this was sufficient.

Other interesting solutions (I have yet to fully implement these as exercises) are: using a chain of processes each manifesting a counter, as in the question; and making full use of the functional nature of Erlang by generating functions from templates in something akin to nested `for` loops.
Both are interesting in their own way.